# Adobe Flash crash after several hours of playing mp3 stream

Tags: flash, stream, crash, cross-browser, mp3

I have made a mp3 player that is working fine, it plays a mp3 radio stream for several hours (last crash was after 6,5 hours) and then it crashes without any message or exception.
This is very difficult to debug because it only happen after a couple of hours with the same stream. It appear in all browsers so it is a Adobe Flash problem or is this a buffer problem? Must i use other buffering settings to play MP3 streams?

Does anybody know this problem and what can be done to avoid this?

Also another question is why memory consumption after hibernation of the pc is growing dramaticly (every second it eats a couple of 10Kb). After refreshing the page it is stable again. Why is this happening?

Mp3 player is made in Flash 9 (CS3) with AS3 and the player is Flash 10 (latest). Running on Windows XP Prof with 3GB RAM.

Comment: If you post your code we can see if there's anything suspicious.

Comment: see comment below. I don't think it is a problem of my code.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a memory leak, which to fix usually involves looking over all of your code and making sure there are no issues.

There are a handful of sites out there that talk about the best way to manage memory in Actionscript. (I am assuming AS3)

one such place can be found here: http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/06/as3_resource_ma.html

Comment: Ah, thanks. I don't think it is a problem of my code because it loads the stream and does nothing special with it, flash handles the stream and plays it. Maybe a memory leak of flash itself?